# Typescript array element Date not working

Tags: angular, typescript, date, angular-date-format

I am trying to compare various Date elements like this one
2 date elements that represent date formats but not being able to compare both cause it is displayed that "**core.js:6237 ERROR TypeError: newticketList.createdAt.toDateString is not a function**". And this as well with any other function like getDate or getMonth
ps.: I already searched that it can be not recognized as a Date format, but in this case how can I go around it?

```
 ticketList: Array<Ticket>;
let dateTime = new Date()
```

(...)

```
this.ticketList = this.ticketList.filter(
      newticketList => (newticketList.createdAt.toDateString() != dateTime.toDateString()))
```

Comment: Perhaps `this.ticketList[*].createdAt` is null. Try inspecting it in the JavaScript debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done.
although both vars are set as Date inside they were being handled as String
So the solution was instead of:

```
newticketList => 
        (newticketList.createdAt.toDateString() != dateTime.toDateString()))
```

We get this:

```
newticketList => 
        (new Date(newticketList.createdAt).toDateString() != dateTime.toDateString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

`createdAt` does no contain a method called `toDateString`

```
this.ticketList.map(
  newticketList => console.log(newticketList.createdAt));
```

And check what you get out

Comment: ty, with the console log I got the idea of how to fix it